# The beginning of the page to add a logo similar thing

Tags: header-footer, captions, vertical-alignment

[image]

As seen in the above image, there is a picture of the same size in eps format. I've set the page margins, according to the eps file. This picture is an example only.

I want to use this file at the beginning of pages. But I do not want to use on all pages. Only the relevant pages.

[image]

I want to do as above.

But,

[image]

[image]

The results are not encouraging at all. I use `\includegraphics` code. So we perceive as text the eps file. I hope to solve this problem with your help.

Sorry for my English.

```
    \documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extarticle}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3.4cm,bottom=3.6cm,left=2.2cm,right=2.85cm,columnsep=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example.eps}

\noindent Fuga. Pe et dus sed eictat eaque simpore pudandebis accus natempe dicidipiet veliquae. Dita nobis dolum conecer ferum, quas derspel ipsus.
Rionem est quatium quis mi, simusanita int adiorempor solupti busaest as et alis dolorep raerro in corum volutem. Aperion sequae eiumendel ipsum ut estruptatem quate dolesequis estis ad most, occum sequam santo core quo blatur? Lut et illit, officip icipis dit earum ratem quam eaquatin rent et etur repel et eatur? Tio. Nem adi utatius eaturi con cor sed eos dio officiae soluptati as doluptas ulparch iliquam harum fugia consequi am, volupis sitat.

\newpage

\noindent Fuga. Pe et dus sed eictat eaque simpore pudandebis accus natempe dicidipiet veliquae. Dita nobis dolum conecer ferum, quas derspel ipsus.
Rionem est quatium quis mi, simusanita int adiorempor solupti busaest as et alis dolorep raerro in corum volutem. Aperion sequae eiumendel ipsum ut estruptatem quate dolesequis estis ad most, occum sequam santo core quo blatur? Lut et illit, officip icipis dit earum ratem quam eaquatin rent et etur repel et eatur? Tio. Nem adi utatius eaturi con cor sed eos dio officiae soluptati as doluptas ulparch iliquam harum fugia consequi am, volupis sitat.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at `background` package or `eso-pic` .....

Comment: Basically, you want to overlay part of an image but not all.  The easiest way to do this is simply reserve the space not overlaid and overlay the entire image on top.  \rlap, \llap and/or \smash can be used to overlay things, and \rule{0pt}{1in}\newline will reserve 1in of vertical space.  Starting and stopping the columns is a lot easier with the multicolumn package.

Comment: @HarishKumar, thank you! esp-pic package worked.

Thank you John.

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Done. Thanks. Happy new year. :)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest option for you will be to use `eso-pic` or `background` packages. Here is an example of `eso-pic` package. Now, since you want it to appear on only some pages, we define a macro:

```
\newcommand{\addpicture}[1][example-image-a]{%
 \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
   \AtPageMyUpperLeft{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#1}}
  }
  }
```

and use `\addpicture[<optional picture>` in the page where the picture is needed.  Here `\AtPageMyUpperLeft` is defined as

```
\newcommand\AtPageMyUpperLeft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \put(\LenToUnit{1cm},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){#1}}}
```

Change `1cm` here as you wish.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extarticle}
\usepackage[top=3.4cm,bottom=3.6cm,left=2.2cm,right=2.85cm,columnsep=0.75cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageMyUpperLeft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \put(\LenToUnit{1cm},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){#1}}}

\newcommand{\addpicture}[1][example-image-a]{%
 \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
   \AtPageMyUpperLeft{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{#1}}
  }
  }

\begin{document}

\addpicture

\noindent Fuga. Pe et dus sed eictat eaque simpore pudandebis accus natempe dicidipiet veliquae. Dita nobis dolum conecer ferum, quas derspel ipsus.
Rionem est quatium quis mi, simusanita int adiorempor solupti busaest as et alis dolorep raerro in corum volutem. Aperion sequae eiumendel ipsum ut estruptatem quate dolesequis estis ad most, occum sequam santo core quo blatur? Lut et illit, officip icipis dit earum ratem quam eaquatin rent et etur repel et eatur? Tio. Nem adi utatius eaturi con cor sed eos dio officiae soluptati as doluptas ulparch iliquam harum fugia consequi am, volupis sitat.

\clearpage

\noindent Fuga. Pe et dus sed eictat eaque simpore pudandebis accus natempe dicidipiet veliquae. Dita nobis dolum conecer ferum, quas derspel ipsus.
Rionem est quatium quis mi, simusanita int adiorempor solupti busaest as et alis dolorep raerro in corum volutem. Aperion sequae eiumendel ipsum ut estruptatem quate dolesequis estis ad most, occum sequam santo core quo blatur? Lut et illit, officip icipis dit earum ratem quam eaquatin rent et etur repel et eatur? Tio. Nem adi utatius eaturi con cor sed eos dio officiae soluptati as doluptas ulparch iliquam harum fugia consequi am, volupis sitat.

\clearpage
\addpicture[example-image-b]
\noindent Fuga. Pe et dus sed eictat eaque simpore pudandebis accus natempe dicidipiet veliquae. Dita nobis dolum conecer ferum, quas derspel ipsus.
Rionem est quatium quis mi, simusanita int adiorempor solupti busaest as et alis dolorep raerro in corum volutem. Aperion sequae eiumendel ipsum ut estruptatem quate dolesequis estis ad most, occum sequam santo core quo blatur? Lut et illit, officip icipis dit earum ratem quam eaquatin rent et etur repel et eatur? Tio. Nem adi utatius eaturi con cor sed eos dio officiae soluptati as doluptas ulparch iliquam harum fugia consequi am, volupis sitat.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Happy new year :-)